# WSA Windows Sockets: прокси и таймаут

Tags: windows, сокет, winsock

Подскажите, как в сокетах сделать таймаут для конкретного сокета. Передал сокет в WSASend или WSARecv, и он там висит, пока не будет данных, а порой нужно закрыть его, если данных долго нет.

И второй вопрос, нужно сделать прокси. Вызываю WSARecv, получаю данные из другого сокета, нужно отослать в этот. Но на нем уже вызван WSARecv, и вызов WSASend может вызвать ошибку. Как реализовать посылку данных в сокет?

Answer (score 0):

Решение Вашей задачи - [select](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740141(v=vs.85).aspx). Список всех сокетов, с которыми нужно работать, заносятся в специальный массив. Также уточняется, чего именно от каждого сокета ожидается. Последний параметр - время ожидания. Если за указанное время ни с одним сокетом ничего не случиться - функция завершит свою работу.

Обычно эту функцию вставляют в цикл. Пришли данные - функция завершилась, обработали/послали данные и снова вызываем функцию.

Ещё примеры:

- [известное руководство от Beej](http://www.beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/multipage/selectman.html).
- [Разница в работе с сокетами Windows и Linux](http://rsdn.ru/forum/info/FAQ.network.socket.winlin).
- [Программирование сокетов в Linux](http://rsdn.ru/article/unix/sockets.xml) - хоть и для Линукса, но для общего развития полезно почитать.
- [Самоучитель игры на winsock](http://kpnc.opennet.ru/sock.pdf) - это просто интересно почитать.
- [Полное руководство по сетевому программированию для разработчиков игр](http://gamedev.ru/articles/?id=80201).

Comment: Это даже не смешно. Я использую select уже хрен знает сколько лет. Да, он универсальный, одинаково работает на всех операционных системах. У меня написана куча версий серверов. Но к сожалению select довольно тормозной. WSARecv оказалось быстрее. (хотя, стоит пересмотреть мою реализацию.)

Мне все же хотелось бы узнать, как сделать то, что мне надо используя WSA функции. (WSASelect естественно не подходит.)

Comment: Я даже боюсь спросить, что же там за данные такие бегают, что оно такое тормозное?

Конечно, когда читать с одного сокета напрямую, то оно будет быстро. Но если нужно читать десять сокетов, то тут либо 10 потоков, либо select и его аналоги (poll  к примеру).

Но если уж так сильно нужно, то, может, посмотреть в сторону асинхронных сокетов? Там функция чтения будет отрабатывать быстро, но данные будут приходить в виде windows message.

Comment: Да обычный прокси. Вызываю постоянно select для всех открытых сокетов.

Ну так WSA и есть асинхронные функции. Вызвал WSARecv и ждешь, пока отработает. Но с ним вопрос, как его прервать, если уже вызван WSARecv, а теперь появились данные, и надо вызвать WSASend.

Comment: Сами себе противоречите. 

> WSA и есть асинхронные функции. Вызвал WSARecv и ждешь

Либо асинхронные, либо ждешь. Если асинхронно и ждать - то это цикл вида

    while (достаточно данных) {
      recv(..);
      ..
    }

Вообще то, пока с сокет висит на блокирующем чтении, в него можно писать (например, в другом потоке). В видне не пробовал, но в линуксе работает на ура (для обычных tcp сокетов).

с select начинаются проблемы, если сокетов много. Если больше 1024 - там начинаются свои проблемы (просто не работает).

Я думаю, что Вам нужен [iocp](http://habrahabr.ru/post/59282/).

Comment: В смысле вызвал и ждешь сообщения, а функция не блокируется. Да, IOCP я и использую. Не догадался написать в вопросе, что WSARecv в варианте с IOCP.

У меня все сокеты неблокирующие. Если вызываю recv или send, то перед этим проверяю select'ом, что можно писать/читать. С IOCP хорошо то, что там нет постоянных вызовов select, сообщения приходят сами.

Comment: @mikelsv, здравствуйте, подскажите пожалуйста, Вы смогли найти решение данной проблемы? Как прервать WSASend или WSARecv, который на данный момент находится в очереди порта завершения? То же понадобилось отбивать по тайм-ауте, но не знаю, как. А проблема может быть в следующем: вы, как клиент к примеру вызвали WSARecv, WSARecv поместила задачу на чтение в порт завершения и удаленный сервер к примеру начал передавать данные, а WSARecv принимать их, НО, в какой то момент к примеру удалённый сервер разорвал соединение, то в этом случае-задача WSARecv в очереди порта завершения-останется навсегда.

Comment: вот это да - прошло 7 лет и вопрос решили минусануть. это сильно.